# Check if key exists in Berkeley DB C++ API

Tags: c++, berkeley-db

so this may sound like a stupid question but I have consulted most of the official documentation of the Berkeley DB C++ API and just cannot seem to find an answer. How do you check if a key exists in the Database? Here is some example code.

```
// Database created.

Dbt key(&some_string, some_size);
Dbt data(&some_struct, some_other_size);

database.put(nullptr, &key, &data, 0);

// Now my &some_string key is definitely in the database, and I can easily get it.
// However if I create an identical string to search for the key, I get DB_NOTFOUND

Dbt search_key(&the_same_string, the_same_size);
int ret = database.exists(nullptr, &search_key, 0);

// This returns DB_NOTFOUND.
```

If I pass the original key Dbt object, of course ret is 0. But is there no way to check if a key exists, if you do not already have the associated Dbt object for that exact record?

I have also tried using cursors and Dbc::get() works for finding keys if I set the DB_FIRST flag. But that one automatically writes into whatever data Dbt object I pass.

All I want to do is check if a Dbt object with some specific key exists, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument for instantiating a `Dbt` is just an integer size, not a pointer.  So, for example, your line:

```
Dbt key(&some_string, &some_size);
```

Should become:

```
Dbt key(&some_string, some_size);
```

In addition, if your `some_string` is a `std::string` you'll have to convert it to a plain C character array.  Consider including the `NUL` terminator in the string written to the database.  You don't have to, but it often makes debugging easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The pointer notation for the size was just an oversight here. I didn't have that in my code. Is there any reason why I would have to convert it to plain C? I mean, the documentation states that that a Dbt object can be pretty much anything.

Comment: No.  If you need more help with this, please provide a minimal, verifiable example.  Something that we can compile and run.